# How to pkill by "command name"?

Tags: process, kill

So I'm executing a command like:

```
 COMMANDNAME -PARAMETERS
```

But..why can't I kill it with "pkill"? I'm trying with:

```
 pkill -9 "COMMANDNAME -PARAMETERS"
```

but it doesn't kills the "COMMANDNAME -PARAMETERS" process. Why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need to match the full command line (command + parameters) as you reported in your example you will have to use the `-f` option:

```
pkill -9 -f "COMMANDNAME -PARAMETERS"
```

accordingly to the man page:

```
  -f     The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.
          When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill):

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the
>   process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout. All the
>   criteria have to match.
>   pkill terminates these IDs

So the "commandname -parameters" is not matching. What you should have is just:

> pkill -9 commandname